# My program calculates only the last value

Tags: python, numpy

Here is my code:

```
import numpy as np

cx = np.array([0, 0, 3, 3])
cy = np.array([0, 3, 4, 0])
M = len(cx)

for j in range(M):
    wx = 0
    wy = 0

    for i in range(M):
        if i == j:
            continue
        x = cx[i] - cx[j]
        y = cy[i] - cy[j]
        wx += -x / np.sqrt(x ** 2 + y ** 2)
        wy += -y / np.sqrt(x ** 2 + y ** 2)

Move = (
    wx / np.sqrt(wx ** 2 + wy ** 2),
    wy / np.sqrt(wx ** 2 + wy ** 2),
)
```

What is wrong with my code?
Your help will be highly appreciated

Comment: What are you trying to do, and what is the expected output?

Comment: What is that you are expecting from your code?

Comment: what is the if statement doing here???

Comment: Are you surprised that `wx` and `wy` are the two last values you calculated in the loop?

Comment: Obviously, @Cletus is computing some  normalized pairwise distances.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import numpy as np

cx = np.array([0, 0, 3, 3])
cy = np.array([0, 3, 4, 0])
M = len(cx)

for j in range(M):
    wx = 0
    wy = 0

    for i in range(M):
        if i == j:
            continue
        x = cx[i] - cx[j]
        y = cy[i] - cy[j]
        wx += -x / np.sqrt(x ** 2 + y ** 2)
        wy += -y / np.sqrt(x ** 2 + y ** 2)

        Move = (
        wx / np.sqrt(wx ** 2 + wy ** 2),
        wy / np.sqrt(wx ** 2 + wy ** 2),
        )

    print(Move)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
import numpy as np

cx = np.array([0, 0, 3, 3])
cy = np.array([0, 3, 4, 0])
M = len(cx)

for j in range(M):
    wx = 0
    wy = 0

    for i in range(M):
        if i == j:
            continue
        x = cx[i] - cx[j]
        y = cy[i] - cy[j]
        wx += -x / np.sqrt(x ** 2 + y ** 2)
        wy += -y / np.sqrt(x ** 2 + y ** 2)

    Move = (
        wx / np.sqrt(wx ** 2 + wy ** 2),
        wy / np.sqrt(wx ** 2 + wy ** 2),
    )

    print(Move)
```